# drop down menu needs to display over everything, but it is underneath a certain div

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I have a drop down menu and it works perfectly on everything except IE6 & IE7.

- [Here it is in the Safari/Firefox browsers](http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/1171/picture2ow4.png)
- [Here is how it looks in IE6 & IE7](http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/3897/picture1gc5.png)

Here is the CSS for the div where it hides underneath for IE 6/7

```
#featured-programs-left img,
#featured-programs-right img{
    overflow:auto;
    border:0;
}

#featured-programs-left,
#featured-programs-right {
    height:625px;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:left;
    clear:right;
    width:100%;
}

#featured-programs-left div,
#featured-programs-right div {
    overflow:auto;
    clear:left;
    clear:right;
    width:352px;
    height:345px;
}

#featured-programs-left {
    float:left;
}

#featured-programs-right {
    float:right;
}
```

Here is the jQuery (in the source code you'll see multiple div's within each main div (featured-programs-left & -right) and the jQuery fades each one in and out in a loop) for displaying the multiple items (fades the items in and out) within both sides of the div (#featured-programs-left & #featured-programs-right)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#featured-programs-left').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 15000,
        next:   '#next2',
        prev:   '#prev2' 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#featured-programs-right').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:  'slow',
        timeout: 21000,
        next:   '#next3',
        prev:   '#prev3' 
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS for the quicklinks (quicklinks is the drop down menu of links)

```
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks a:link,
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks a:visited,
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks a:active {
    padding-left: .9em;
    background: transparent url('/site/images/quicklinks_bullet.gif') no-repeat 0em .5em;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks.hover {
    position: relative;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    xleft: -9999em;
    top: 14px;
    width: 142px;
    padding:5px 2px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 90;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #00693E;
    xborder: 1px solid #FDBE2F;
    xborder-width: 0px 1px 1px;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks:hover ul,
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks.hover ul {
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul li {
    background: transparent none;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid #00693E;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul li a:link,
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul li a:visited,
#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent none;
}

#header-nav-top li#quicklinks ul li a:hover {
    color: #C26B1A;
    background: transparent url('/site/images/bullet_link.gif') no-repeat 0% 6px;
}
```

What do you think may be causing it to not show the drop down menu over the items in featured-programs-left & featured-programs-right in IE 6/7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of the picture that's currently obscuring your menu to, say, 0? Have you got a "live" test URL we can look at? Alternatively, on the basis that IE is treating z-index incorrectly, have you got the leeway to position your drop-down menu's HTML after the other elements in the page, thereby bypassing z-index?

**EDIT:** Ah, apparently there's a bug. This [link](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/css-forum/47892-z-index-ignored-by-ie.html) might explain, if not actually help...

Quote from MrTazz:

> When running some special JavaScript
>   it magicaly puts the div in the
>   background. Uppdate the div and it
>   comes back farward.

So maybe try updating the drop-down menu div somehow, just before the page is displayed?

**EDIT:**
From Brad's comment, copied here for the edification of future readers: "This helped me out: http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/ I set #header to have a z-index of 2, and #content to have a z-index of 1." – Brad (5 hours ago)

So, to summarise: there's a z-index bug in IE 6/7. To get around it, explicitly set the z-index for the element(s) that is/are appearing in front of your menu to a low number (e.g. 1), and set the z-index for your menu's container to a slightly higher number (e.g. 2).

Comment: It is on a test server I need to VPN into, so sadly no.

Comment: This helped me out: http://webdemar.com/webdesign/superfish-jquery-menu-ie-z-index-bug/

I set #header to have a z-index of 2, and #content to have a z-index of 1.

Answer (score 1):

I set the #content z-index to 1

and set the z-index of the header, which is where the drop-down navigation is located to 2.